# After Oracle upgraded from 10g to 11g , "Oracle-ORA-01722 invalid number" appeared

Tags: java, linux, oracle11g, upgrade, ora-01722

A java web Project
1.OS:Linux
2.Tomcat upgraded from 1.5 to 1.7
3.Java upgraded from 1.5 to 1.7
4.Oracle upgraded from 10g to 11g

There is a talbe named TBL in oracle and a column named COL defined by NUMBER(38,15).

Before upgrading, there was no problem to put a number(for example:0.123456789012345) into the column or retrieve it by "SELECT TO_CHAR(COL) FROM TBL".

But now,when I use "SELECT TO_CHAR(COL) FROM TBL" , OR "SELECT TO_NUMBER(COL) FROM TBL", the error appears("Oracle-ORA-01722 invalid number").

I confirm the value by “SELECT COL FROM TBL” via Oracle SQL Developer,and it looks like very noraml,just a number like 0.123456789012345.But if I use SQL Plus to confirm the value ,it is blank! This is very strange!

Moreover,when I use the value plus one ,no error encountered but the result is not correct (0.123456789012345 + 1 = 1.123456789012305).

Not every value in that column has the same problem but all value looks like a normal number when I select it via Oracle SQL Developer without TO_CHAR() or TO_NUMBER().

Anyone who has the simliar expierence will help a lot.thank you.

Comment: In one of our projects, we encountered lots of Oracle bugs with 11gR1. Once we upgraded to 11gR2, most of the bugs got resolved. Which release have you upgraded to?

Comment: @ArtBajji 11g R2 64bit